# Azure SQL Server restore using .bak file

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have created a SQL Server in Azure and have downloaded the Azure Data Studio. I have a SQL Server database backup file (`.bak`) and connected to the sever that I created from Azure Data Studio and I am not seeing an option to restore the database.

I just have the back up file available and don't have any on perm database available and I want to directly restore the database to the Azure SQL Server.

Comment: Is it a SQL Server in Azure or an Azure SQL Database (which is what you've tagged)? For the latter, you can't restore a `.bak` to them, you'd need to use a different technology such as a DACPAC and/or BACPAC.

Comment: This project on GitHub might help you: https://github.com/grrlgeek/bak-to-bacpac

Comment: Hi @karas27, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Comment: @JosephXu Nope was able to deploy with the approach you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure SQL database currently does not support this feature. The only way to restore a SQL database in Azure is to import from a BACPAC file as @Larnu said. You can follow this guide to use a BACPAC file to [migrate to an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/migrate-to-database-from-sql-server).

**Another option:**
If you get an account to connect to the local server.You can use SQL Management Studio to migrate it directly to Azure.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Azure Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) to perform an [assessment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-assesssqlonprem?view=sql-server-ver15) and migrate to Azure SQL from a local database.

Answer (score 0):

While both replies before mine are correct I want to add something.

You have 3 ways to migrate with a right click:

1. SSMS: Task > Deploy Database to SQL Azure , which will create a `BACPAK` file, not a `.bak` file.
2. DMA: Assess and migrate
3. Azure Data Studio: I discovered in [this video](https://info.microsoft.com/ww-ondemand-assess-your-sql-server-estate-with-azure-migrate.html?lcid=en-us) at minute 00:35 that you can actually use Azure Data Studio with some preview functionality that will help you migrate. I haven't found any plugin and in the video there is a Microsoft e-mail so I asked to try the preview. I don't expect to be better than DMA which is the go-to tool for migration.

**EDIT:** I sent an e-mail to Microsoft which replied to me

*"Hi Francesco,
Thanks for reaching out. We are currently in private preview in East US2 region. Will that work for you ?  We will soon be expanding to other regions, so please stay tuned."*

So one day migration through Azure Data Studio will be possible but for now it's only to East US2 region